# Update joomla database with variable

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have tried working with Joomla Framework and I got my update working, but how do I update with a variable. Fx:

```
$test = 'Hello';
$fields = array(
$db->quoteName('test_column') . ' = ' . $db->quote('$test')
);
```

How do I write the `$test` variable in this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php, you want to single quote (`'`) strings when you want to output them as you see them, and double quotes (`"`) when you want the string to be parsed for variables. All you need to do is change the quotes around `$test` , or more simply remove them as they aren't needed here:

```
$test = 'Hello';
$fields = array(
  $db->quoteName('test_column') . ' = ' . $db->quote($test)
);
```